Flutter handle play video
If you're having trouble watching movies, the general overview is that after receiving data transmitted from the "link_embed" api, video_player or webview_flutter will be used to handle video playback.
However, now after successfully receiving the data, I am unable to play the video and only display a black screen.
Hope everyone can help me, thank you,, ,,,
However, now after successfully receiving the data, I am unable to play the video and only display a black screen.
Hope everyone can help me, thank you

You need to call setState()  after calling intialize. Follow the docs and see the complete example here.
See a brief example
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(Uri.parse(
        'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4'))
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

